# using dplyr's recode to recode only some numeric values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

it's important to me to recode using pipes, so, please don't offer base R solutions, please.

Also important: I have both libraries activated: car and tidyverse.

So, I have a data frame x. I want to produce a new column c and then recode ONLY the value of 3 in it as 300. The following is working when I want to replace with an integer, but what if I need to recode into a float?

Thank you!

```
library(car)
library(tidyverse)
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 3:1)
x %>% mutate(c = a*b) %>% mutate(c = dplyr::recode(c, `3` = 300L)) # Works
x %>% mutate(c = a*b) %>% mutate(c = dplyr::recode(c, `3` = 0.333)) # Doesn't work
```

Comment: Change the last bit to `mutate(c = ifelse(c == 3, 300, c)`

Comment: @Phil I can't - in real life I have to recode more than 1 value, in other words I want to recode 3 into something and 1 into something, but not the rest.

Comment: `case_when()` is specifically designed for this.

Comment: `mutate(c = case_when(c == 3 ~ 300, c == 1 ~ 'something', TRUE ~c))`

Comment: @Axeman I tried:  x %>% mutate(c = a*b) %>% mutate(c = case_when(c == 3 ~ 300, TRUE ~c)), but it gives an error: Evaluation error: must be type double, not integer

Comment: Btw, this happens because `c` is an integer, and `0.333` isn't. The `L` in `300L` specifies that number should be of type integer. `case_when` just has a slightly more specific error message.

Comment: All replacements must be the same type.  If you enter `typeof(x$c)` you'll see that it's an integer so explicitly defining the replacement value as an integer works.  If you were to set the variable `c` as numeric, then the second command would work.

Comment: So, what is the solution? I mean, in general: have I really asked a complicated question? In base R it's so easy to do, is it really so complicated in dplyr?

Comment: All `dplyr` functions are more type strict than base, this include `recode`, `if_else` and `case_when`. The solution is to specify your types (or to not use `dplyr`).

Comment: x %>% mutate(c = a * b) %>% mutate(case_when(c == 3 ~ 300L, TRUE ~ c)) works, but this one doesn't: x %>% mutate(c = a * b) %>% mutate(case_when(c == 3 ~ 0.3, TRUE ~ c)). How can I recode into a different type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? If you change `c` to double you can then use double precision (decimals). Per @Axeman and @Jay's comments, it maintiains the type across the variable.

```
x %>% mutate(c = a*b) %>% mutate(c = dplyr::recode(as.double(c), `3` = 0.333))

  a b     c
1 1 3 0.333
2 2 2 4.000
3 3 1 0.333
```